# A question about \ifcase syntax

Tags: conditionals, syntax

The command `\today` has been defined as follows:

```
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
```

My problem is about `\ifcase <number><case0>\or<case1>\or...\else<defaultcase>\fi`.
what is the `<case0>` in the above example? `\month` or `{}`? What does it means?

Comment: `\ifcase<integer> <case 0> \or <case 1> \or ... \fi` selects the case according to the integer. So yes, this does nothing if `\month` equals `0`.

Comment: Is is possible that `\month` equals` 0`?

Comment: No, probably not. But still you want to make sure that you get January for `\month=1`, and `\ifcase` starts counting at `0`.

Comment: And isn't `\month` return month name or its number?

Comment: `\month` should be an integer for this to work.

Comment: By default `\month` is an internal count register that on program startup is populated with the number of the current month (between 1 and 12, obviously).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<case 0>` text is empty.

Indeed, `\month` is an “internal integer”, so `\ifcase\month` is a complete conditional test (in the sense that TeX will not do a look ahead with expansion in order to see whether a space follows).

TeX processes `\ifcase` as follows; suppose there are *m* `\or` tokens.

1. the `<integer>` value is determined, either by looking up the value of a register or by evaluating an explicit constant, let's say it's *n*;
2. if *n* < 0 or *n* > *m*, then TeX skips tokens up to (and including) `\else` or up to (and excluding) `\fi` if no `\else` comes along;
3. if 0 ≤ *n* ≤ *m*, tokens are skipped up to (and including) the *n*-th `\or`.

Since there is no “0-th” `\or`, *no* text at all is skipped when the `<integer>` evaluates to 0.

What happens to the following `\or` tokens and text between them? The expansion of `\or` consists in skipping tokens (without expansion) up to (and including) the matching `\fi`. Text between `\else` and `\fi` disappears in the same way, when *n* = *m*.

---

Can `\month` be zero or negative? Certainly so. The register's value is computed and assigned to at the beginning of the job with the number corresponding to the current month, but the register is writable and saying `\month=0` (or any other integer value) would simply change the stored value (with obvious impact on dates, but that's another matter).

Assuming `\month` holds the value 11, upon expansion of `\today`, the input stream will contain

```latex
\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year
```

TeX will now look at the value of `\month` and skip the first eleven `\or`, after removing `\ifcase\month`; this leaves

```latex
November\or December\fi\space\number\day, \number\year
```

Next `November` is passed to the next stage of processing (usually for printing) and the input stream will have

```latex
\or December\fi\space\number\day, \number\year
```

The expansion of `\or` consists in removing (without expansion) all tokens up to `\fi`:

```latex
\space\number\day, \number\year
```

and processing will go on by expanding `\space`.

In the (unlikely) event that `\month` has the value 0, nothing would be skipped after removal of `\ifcase\month`; the text up to `\fi` will be removed by the expansion of `\or` as in the previous case.

Comment: Such a nice explanation...thanks a lot...